# Laravel 8: Call to a member function user() on array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum project, and I wanted to add some like functionality to question that has been asked on forum by users.

So here is a form on `question.blade.php`:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.likes', $show->id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <button class="btn">
      <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span>{{ $show->likes->count() }}</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

And then at `LikeController`, I added this:

```
public function store(Question $id, Request $request)
    {
        $id->likes()->create([
            'user_id' => $_REQUEST->user()->id,
        ]);

        return back();
    }
```

But now I get this error:

```
Call to a member function user() on array
```

Which is referring to this line:

```
'user_id' => $_REQUEST->user()->id,
```

So what is going wrong here? I need to pass the user id who pressed on like button in order to update `likes` table. How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this with me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `'user_id' => $_REQUEST->user->id`

Comment: @Basharmal Trying to get property 'user' of non-object

Comment: What do you want from this `$_REQUEST->user()->id,` do you want the loged in user id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace    `'user_id' => $_REQUEST->user()->id;`

with        `'user_id' => $request->user();`

**edit : reason to the error**

`$_REQUEST` is  an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.this belongs to core PHP, not to the Laravel. that array doesn't  have connection with laravel `user()` object
so that why the  `Call to a member function user() on array` thrown.

$request is instance of `lluminate\Http\Request`  this object have access to current authenticated user